# How to open pop up window in javascript in drupal 6?

Tags: 6

I have made a custom module in Drupal 6 and want to implement the following: When I click on my link it should open in a pop up window in javascript. But I don't know it how to implement pop up window in Drupal.

Please help me.

This is my link code.

```
l('open pop up','admin/state_user/stateadmin/state/user/disable/'
  . $result -> uid, array('attributes' => array('title' => t('open pop up'))),TRUE);
```

Comment: You can achieve popup using CTools API. Check examples of CTools contributed modules. You will find a code to open modal popup by clicking on link.

Comment: I just wnat to use pop up window in java script only....

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Colorbox](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox) module.

> Colorbox is a light-weight customizable lightbox plugin for jQuery. This module allows for integration of Colorbox into Drupal.
>
> Images, iframed or inline content etc. can be displayed in a overlay
>   above the current page.

You need to activate the iframe method and add the custom iframe class to your link.

Answer (score 0):

Though window.open is not considered as good practice but still if you want to open window in D6 using this then you can do like this.

Create a link

```
<?php echo l('product', 'product', array('attributes' => array('id' => 'product-link'))); ?>
```

Add JavaScript file & add it to theme.info or call it in some custom module.

Write javascript code as

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
  $("#product-link").click(
    function(e) {
      openWindow();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  );
}
);
```